# How to make an arduino pick an individual plant seed?

Tags: mechanisms

I am trying to build a robot which would plant seeds instead of humans doing it (lettuce, radish and so on). The only problem i have so far is picking an individual seed. 
How could i do it? I've seen some discs designed especially for such appliances, but those are really expensive and i think that there has to be an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The [farmbot](https://genesis.farmbot.io/v1.2/docs/seed-injector) uses a small diameter tube and a vacuum pump to pick up a single seed.

[image]